# Uploading Fast sketches to Internet with Wacom Drawing Board and Phone?

Tags: drawing-tablet, drawing, sketching

Suppose I have some phone and some Wacom drawing board (I have actually many Wacom boards so suppose any of them). I do not want to plug the Wacom board into my computer but to plug it to my phone (which can be what-ever). Does there exist some phone with which I could fast draw things and then fast upload pictures to Internet?

I find irritating that I need to use Laptop / Phone / Wacom -board to upload fast sketches to internet.

Answer (score 3):

There are good sketching apps for tablets, like [Sketchbook](http://m.autodesk.com/mobile/servlet/product?siteID=17221380&id=17426479) and [Ideas](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobeideas.html). Even Wacom has [Bamboo Paper](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/06/18/wacoms-bamboo-paper-for-ipad-is-ok-inking-app-but-lacks-features/) for Android and iOS, but there's currently no off-the-shelf way to connect a Wacom tablet directly to a mobile device. Samsung demoed a Wacom pen-enabled Tab at Adobe MAX, and the Samsung Note is already on the market, with the [Galaxy Note 10.1](http://www.theverge.com/products/galaxy-note-10-1-wi-fi/5263) scheduled for release this year.

Comment: [Wacom support has confirmed as much](http://forum.wacom.eu/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8884). On a side note, the Eben E3 uses a Wacom sensor/pen too.

Comment: The idea of sketching on a phone, or even sketching using the phone as a display, makes my eyes hurt. :/

Comment: Looking forward to a future with pressure-sensitive e-ink touch screens...

Comment: @Alan: The display isn't really a problem. With most Android phones, they're big enough and high enough resolution, it's about the same as using one of those pocket-sized notepads. The real problem is having no stylus and the screen texture (or lack thereof). The second problem is that Android doesn't seem to have any decent drawing apps.

Comment: I'm kinda digging Autodesk's Sketchbook Express and Adobe Ideas and Collage on my Android tablet, but I wouldn't use them on my phone. I couldn't imagine making a useful sketch on a tiny pocket pad, either, so perhaps it's a personal preference (or my aging eyeballs!). Lack of pressure-sensitivity is a bit of a pain, but given that iPad was intended to be entirely fingers only, it's certainly not an insurmountable barrier.

Answer (score 1):

No. All Wacom devices require a computer.

Even the Inkling requires a computer to manage the sketches you create with it.

You would need to simply use an app on the phone to sketch if you want the images directly on the phone.